# Gson parsing of multiple arrays with unknown fields

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

My goal is to parse a JSON response of following structure

```
{
"request":{"timestamp":1531826474,"version":1.1},
"Server1":["player1", "player2", "player3"],
"Server2:"["player1", "player2", "player3"],
[...]
}
```

by mirroring the class structure and using a custom deserializer to iterate through the keys and remove the request part, as I don't need it in this scenario. Server and player names are unknown, amount of each varies.

```
public class WynnWorld {

    private List<String> players;

    public WynnWorld(List<String> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public List<String> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(List<String> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }
}
```

Previously the list was contained in a separate class, but in hopes of using Gson's array mapping that was given up.

**Deserializer:**

```
public class JSONDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<WynnWorld>> {

    @Override
    public List<WynnWorld> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
        jsonObject.remove("request");
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        List<WynnWorld> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Parsing: "+entry.getValue());
            list.add(context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), WynnWorld.class));
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

I've spent the past hours switching out types, adding/removing classes to no avail, with the current version running into
`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $` despite providing a list. It is obvious that my attempts all lack some kind of understanding, so a clue would be greatly appreciated.

**Parsing attempt:**

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(WynnWorld.class, new JSONDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
List<WynnWorld> response = gson.fromJson(returnString.toString(), new TypeToken<List<WynnWorld>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wynworld is an object that contains a list. You try to parse an array. The result of parsing can not be auto assigned to the Wynworld object.

Try something like that

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
        List<String> players = context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), listType);
        WynnWorld wynnWorld = new WynnWorld(players);
        list.add(wynnWorld);
    }
```

Comment: Messed around with it a bit, but it still seems to run into the same error. Oddly enough it doesn't seem like the deserializer is even called doing that as test prints are ignored, might be setting the TypeToken causes some issues.

Comment: That seems to happen because you register JSONDeserializer for WynnWorld and not for List<WynnWorld>. Try this:

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new JSONDeserializer());

Comment: Used List<WynnWorld> for the token instead, but it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!